# Top vs Rank/Row Number functions - Which performs higher?

Tags: sql-server, optimization

I attempted to Google the Cost of using Top in a query vs using a Ranking or Row_Number type function.

Does the cost of each depend on the situation or can the cost of these two features be determined across the board for all situations?

Some mock SQL is below using a simple CTE to demonstrate my question would look like the below:

```
WITH fData AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS ID, 'John' AS fName, 'Black' AS lName, CAST('05/19/1975' AS DATE) AS birthDate UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS ID, 'John' AS fName, 'Black' AS lName, CAST('04/1/1989' AS DATE) AS birthDate UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS ID, 'John' AS fName, 'Black' AS lName, CAST('11/16/1995' AS DATE) AS birthDate UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 AS ID, 'John' AS fName, 'Black' AS lName, CAST('01/16/1968' AS DATE) AS birthDate UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 AS ID, 'John' AS fName, 'Black' AS lName, CAST('01/16/1968' AS DATE) AS birthDate
)   

/* Using TOP 1 vs Row_Number() - Uncomment this and comment the below to VIEW TOP version */
--SELECT TOP 1 d.ID, d.fName, d.lName, d.birthDate
--FROM fData d
--ORDER BY d.birthDate

/* Using the below vs TOP 1 */
SELECT * FROM
(   SELECT d.ID, d.fName, d.lName, d.birthDate, Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY d.birthDate) AS ranker
    FROM fData d
) r
WHERE r.ranker = 1
```

When using TOP there's not a need to apply a secondary Wrapping query around it and it looks cleaner.  After applying a Row_Number or a Ranking function you then must wrap it to tell the query which row you are now wanting... either by applying the WHERE ranker = 1 or ranker >= 5 to achieve the same as TOP 1 or TOP 5.

Which is better faster if this is even something that can be determined?

Comment: Have a look at the query plans. You'll notice that the query plan for a `TOP (1)` compared to using `ROW_NUMBER` and then `WHERE {ROW_NUMBER()} = 1` are quite different. [Simple example](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkE8ermpY)

Comment: They solve a different problem - top is for when you want a single row across your entire result set. Row number is for when you want the top row of each partition.

Comment: It can certainly be determined (with the execution plan) but always be very careful to draw general conclusions, as only very rarely can blanket statements about construct X always being faster than construct Y being made. Query context matters a lot. (Also, [do not use locale-dependent date formats](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166771/what-date-time-literal-formats-are-language-and-dateformat-safe).)

Comment: ^^ Well yes very true however after coming from Oracle that does NOT have TOP to now being in a SQL Server Shop... TOP is used all over the place and it's nice... but I see also all over the place Row_Number() functions put in place and then or course are then wrapped with a filter of WHERE ranker = 1... ALL OF THE TIME.  WHY use ranker functions in SQL Server when it has TOP?

These two features solve the SAME Problem more than I see them solving different problems.

Comment: A `ROW_NUMBER()` clause with a `PARTITION BY` can't be replaced with a `TOP` (or at least not without considerable difficulty). Ditto if you have multiple such orderings; a single query with multiple `ROW_NUMBER()`s that you later filter could outperform a bunch of separate ones using `TOP`. The simple form you have written would indeed (realistically) always be done with `TOP` in T-SQL and not `ROW_NUMBER()`, but there's a reason `ROW_NUMBER()` was added to the language.

Comment: It's a pretty contrived example anyway due to the constructed table. A better example might be two real tables joined together. It would probably depend on the density of the `top 1` side: high density/low selectivity means `top 1` is probably faster, low density probably ranking functions are faster. If there is no indexing then ranking functions are usually faster either way. YMMV basically. Every situation is different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of your example the `TOP` is somewhat more efficient.

The execution plan for `TOP` is below

[image]

The `TOP N` sort with `N=1` just needs to keep track of the row with the lowest `birthDate` that it sees.

For the row_number query it recognises that the row number is always ascending and does itself add a `TOP 1` to the plan but it doesn't combine the separated `TOP` and `SORT` into a `TOP N Sort` - so it does a full sort of all 5 rows.

[image]

In the case that an index supplies rows in the desired order without the need for a sort there won't be much in it. The row_number query will have an extra couple of operators that are fairly inexpensive anyway.

> WHY use ranking functions in SQL Server when it has TOP

Ranking functions in general are more powerful than `TOP`.

For the cases where both would work consider that `TOP` is a fairly ancient proprietary syntax and not standard SQL. It was in the product a long time before window functions were added. If portable SQL is a concern you should not use `TOP`.

Though you might not use ranking functions either. As another (standard SQL) alternative is

```
SELECT d.ID, d.fName, d.lName, d.birthDate
FROM fData d
ORDER BY d.birthDate
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY
```

which gives the same plan as `TOP 1`

Comment: It's a pretty contrived example anyway due to the constructed table. A better example might be two real tables joined together. It would probably depend on the density of the `top 1` side: high density/low selectivity means `top 1` is probably faster, low density probably ranking functions are faster.

Comment: Well - the goal of asking such a generic question was not to overload the question with TMI... the basic CTE got the point across I feel like.  But to be sure that I wasn't directly asking to know which of those two very basic queries in my example were faster... I just wasn't sure if there was anything across the board that could be said about the speed of TOP vs Ranking functions in general.  But seems to be more of a situational problem.  The right tool for the job in this case.  I marked this as the answer due to the time and effort spent on such a generic question.